# Tics on y axis in geom_bar not showing up

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have code like this:

```
data <- read.csv("test2.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

# Graph
myplot=ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=condition)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ffffb2", "#fecc5c"))+
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80))+
    ylab("Performance (ns/day) on Extreme") +
    facet_wrap(~specie,nrow=3, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85)) +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))


myplot + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.title=element_blank(), 
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 20))
```

My data is this:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(specie = c("gmx mdrun -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", "gmx mdrun  -s benchPEP.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", 
"gmx mdrun  -s benchPEP.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", "gmx mdrun  -s benchPEP-h.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", 
"gmx mdrun  -s benchPEP-h.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", "gmx mdrun  -s MD_5NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", 
"gmx mdrun  -s MD_5NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", "gmx mdrun  -s data/MD_10NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", 
"gmx mdrun  -s data/MD_10NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", "gmx mdrun -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 ", 
"gmx mdrun -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000 "), condition = c("CUDA", 
"SYCL", "CUDA", "SYCL", "CUDA", "SYCL", "CUDA", "SYCL", "CUDA", 
"SYCL", "CUDA", "SYCL"), value = c("54.682", "77.649", "0.673", 
"0.841", "0.86", "0.986", "452.48", "158 .277", "81.426", "80.454", 
"33.449", "34.363")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I did set ticks on y axis via:

```
scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80))+
```

but they are not showing up. Please advise how to fix this. If I don't include scale_y_discrete decimal values are showing up on y axis which is not what I want.

Comment: Your `value` data is set to character. Use `as.numeric()` on it before the `ggplot2` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using `as.numeric()` as @Phil suggests in a comment, I removed whitespace from one of the values (158 .277). If you find additional NAs are introduced in the full data frame, the `value` column may require some clean up before coercing to numeric.

With the y-axis data set as a numeric, you don't necessarily need to adjust the scales yourself. In your `theme()` you set `axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)` and then add `axis.text.x=element_blank()`, so I have only kept the latter in these plots.

```r
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)
myplot <- data %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=condition)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ffffb2", "#fecc5c"))+
  ylab("Performance (ns/day) on Extreme") +
  facet_wrap(~specie,nrow=3, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 20))

myplot
```

[image]

If you decide you do want to control the y-axis, you would use `scale_y_continuous()` instead of `discrete`.

```r
myplot +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,50,250,400))
```

[image]

```r
myplot +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_extended(n = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>